# Highlight row based on indent level not using SharePoint Designer

Tags: formatting

I would like to have a conditional formatting of the rows in my SharePoint task list table. The table contains (parent) tasks and sub-tasks.

As an example, I would like to shade the parent tasks grey and make them bold, while keeping the sub-tasks in the normal format. This should be done automatically depending on whether the line is a task or sub-task.

Is there a way to fix this? Please note that I cannot use SharePoint Designer..

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Note: The 'Predecessors' column has to be displayed in the list view for this solution to work**

Create a JSLink file and link it to the task list view.

Creating and configuring JSLink can be done using below link,

[Use JSLink for SharePoint Lists](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/01/add-task-status-indicators-in-sharepoint-2013-using-js-link/)

The code that goes into the js file will be,

```
(function () {
var titleFieldCtx = {};

titleFieldCtx.Templates = {};
titleFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "LinkTitle": { //
        "View": TitleFieldViewTemplate 
    }
};

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
    titleFieldCtx
);
```

})();

function TitleFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {

```
var item = ctx.CurrentItem;

//The Predecessors column has to be displayed in the view, otherwise this code fails
if(item.Predecessors.length == 0){ // if the task does not have any predecessors
    return "<b>" + item.Title +  "</b>"; //apply the necessary styling to the title
}
else{
    return item.Title;
}
```

}

Here is a screenshot of how the list view looks after linking the view to the JSLink file,

[image]